# IBM Worklight - client-side API "overrideBackButton" doesn't work the second time

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I want to make something happen when back button is pressed so I put this code in my app's .js file:

```
function wlCommonInit(){            
    // Common initialization code goes here
    WL.App.overrideBackButton(backFunc);
}

function backFunc(){
    alert('You will back to previous page');
}
```

After building and deploying the application and running it in a device, the alert is shown when I press the Back button.

If I now exit the app by pressing on the Home button and kill the app's process, and then open the app again and press the Back button - it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your code INSIDE wlCommonInit(). I suggest to do so in this manner:

```
function wlCommonInit() {
    WL.App.overrideBackButton(backFunc);      
}

function backFunc() {
    alert('You will back to previous page');
}
```

**Edit**: Question updated with the above code snippet and new information based on the comments. Scenario works fine. See comments.

Comment: I have tried it but it didn't work...
my friend have tried it too, in the first time it worked, but for the second time and so on, it didn't worked anymore...

Comment: Sounds... weird. What does logcat show the second time? Please edit your question with your full JavaScript implementation so that this question won't be theoretical...

Comment: I found this on worklight Console : 
Unhandled exception caught: null
                                  org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:952)
                                  org.eclipse.jetty.http.AbstractGenerator.blockForOutput(AbstractGenerator.java:518)
                                  org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:182)
                                  org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:101)
                                  org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1263)

Comment: Please first do what I asked for in my previous comment.

Comment: What are you testing this on? Android (which version)? Windows Phone 7.5? Windows Phone 8? Emulator (which version?)

Comment: I tested that in Android Emulator version 4.0 (API level 15)...
and my friend tested that in his real device (Android) for the same version too...
I also have tested that in my Device (Android) version 2.3.6 and it doesn't work....

Comment: Please edit the question with the steps you're taking. What do you mean by "second time"? Do you: 1) open app 2) click the back button 3) press a button in the dialog, and now what? how do you exit the app? did you alter the code? do you click the home button? Please explain in DETAIL.

Comment: first time after use that code, my friend run the app in his android phone step : 1) open app, 2) click menu button 3) click back button, and it works...
after that he closed that app... some minute later he opened that app again and do the same thing but, the overrideBackButton doesn't worked...

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question with this information. I'll try to recreate it.

Comment: Okay, I created a new AVD using Android 4.2.2, and run the app on it. I clicked the back button and got the alert. I then clicked on the Home button and used the multi-tasking feature to close (quit) the app. I then opened it again and pressed the back button - I got the alert. The code works.

Comment: If there is any other information you did not mention, please do mention it.

Comment: thanks it's worked now, I forgot to clean the android project yesterday, maybe that's the problem that cause the code didn't take effect..